Android Studio cannot add devices
I have a problem with android studio, it cannot add devices.Help me
https://i.sstatic.net/OlPuFsu1.png
https://i.sstatic.net/AJYFsZg8.png
https://i.sstatic.net/xFDsZ74i.png
https://i.sstatic.net/TMQ5560J.png

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: component must be shown on the screen (com.android.tools.adtui.actions.DropDownAction$2[,2147483647,2147483647,26x24,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl$ActionButtonBorder@41ef2c77,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=])
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPopupMenuImpl$MyMenu.show(ActionPopupMenuImpl.java:117)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.JBPopupMenu.showBelow(JBPopupMenu.java:117)
at com.android.tools.adtui.actions.DropDownAction.showPopupMenu(DropDownAction.java:154)
at com.android.tools.adtui.actions.DropDownAction.actionPerformed(DropDownAction.java:128)
t

I try to reinstall but it's not change

Seems to be an UI related error. Android Studio has a "modern UI" and and older version (which is IMHO way better). If one doesn't work on your system because of a bug try the other. You can change it in settings if I remember correctly.
